# Save image files in web application, java

Tags: sql, angularjs, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

> In my web Application, I want to allow "client side users" to upload large amount of image files, and "customer side users" must able to see a grid of uploaded image files.

In this scenario all image files are entitled for uploading, reading, deleting and editing operations.

Basically I'm using java technologies, But I'm in a doubt,

- What is the most secure and efficient way for doing this kind of huge image file management?
- What is the best suitable technology stack, can be used in this kind of web Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363639/how-spring-boot-jpahibernate-saves-images/50364907#50364907) and go to the `display-image-from-db` branch. The basic approach is the following:

- In the entity you have:

  ```
  @Lob
  private Byte[] image;
  ```
- `ImageController.java` - you get the image via a `MultipartFile`

  ```
  @PostMapping("recipe/{id}/image")
  public String handleImagePost(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam("imagefile") MultipartFile file){

      imageService.saveImageFile(Long.valueOf(id), file);

      return "redirect:/recipe/" + id + "/show";
  }
  ```
- Call the `imageService` to save the image passing the `file` as an argument.
- The service basically copies the image content to a byte array, and finally you assign this byte array to your entity.

  ```
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void saveImageFile(Long recipeId, MultipartFile file) {

  try {
      Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(recipeId).get();

      Byte[] byteObjects = new Byte[file.getBytes().length];

      int i = 0;

      for (byte b : file.getBytes()){
          byteObjects[i++] = b;
      }

      recipe.setImage(byteObjects);

      recipeRepository.save(recipe);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      //todo handle better
      log.error("Error occurred", e);

      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  ```

For the full source code go to the repo, that will definitely help.
However I strongly suggest storing the files on the disk and not in the DB. The DB should only store the path to the files. For such solution here is an example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363639/how-spring-boot-jpahibernate-saves-images/50364907#50364907)

**TL;DR**

- I would strongly suggest not storing the data in the database itself but on the filesystem. (E.g.: In a folder.)
- This [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) might be also helpful.
- [Here](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/) you find a complete RESTful implementation.

Cheers!

Comment: This is a link-only answer (to a primarily opinion based question). It would be better if the relevant content from the linked sources was included in your answer so if any of the linked pages disappear then the solution is preserved.