# Upload image using Mysql using springboot JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I want to save the image in MySQL database using spring-boot JPA. can someone pleeae suggest me the approach to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363639/how-spring-boot-jpahibernate-saves-images

Comment: IMHO it's a bad idea, I would suggest store the image on a file server and save the path in the database. Saving image in the database not only increase the database size also adds unnecessary processing for retrieval

Comment: suggest me the approach to save path in database